# BLE HID for Braille Device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, talkback, braille

I'm currently developing a Braille Device for visually challenged people. I want to show my device as Braille HID device via BLE which will connect to Google's accessibility "Talkback" and start communicating with it. What parameters should I set in my BLE device to get it discovered as a Braille screen reader in Talkback.
Any help or suggestion would be highly helpful.
Thanks,
Kumar

I tried setting my BLE device as BLE HID device and it was discovered by general bluetooth scanning but not as a Braille Device

Comment: Most BLE devices do not appear when using the general bluetooth scanning you phones settings provide. How did you set your BLE device as BLE HID device?